# is there no lock if I don't use transations in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is there no lock on table or page or row if I don't use transations in sql server. That if I directly write queries no transation statement?

Comment: Even a query with the frequently incorrectly used hint `NOLOCK` produces locks.

Comment: It's impossible to not use transactions if you're modifying data. Single data modification statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) that aren't encased in `BEGIN TRANSACTION` simply begin and end their own transactions, implicitly. Locking and transactions should be seen separately, notwithstanding that the way transactions are used influences what kinds of locks are taken and for how long. If you're looking for a way to reduce locking conflicts, look into things like snapshot isolation.

Comment: Nolock doesn't imply "take no locks" it means don't honour (some) other locks.

Comment: Given that every data changing statement occurs in a transaction, whether or not you manually begin and commit it or not, please elaborate on what you’re asking. Please show the query you are running and what other locks or running queries may exist concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

No, Even though you don't use transaction SQL Server applies transaction to each of the perticular sql statement. However you do not get control over that. SQL server use that when some error occurs while executing any query to abort that query execution.

If you add transation you can run multiple queries in a group and if any fails the whole group fails. This give more control over the query execution